# XML to JSON conversion with tag value 00E11 gives 0

Tags: java, json, xml, parsing

An XML tag value `<ItemName>00E11</ItemName>`
when converted to JSON using

```
JSONObject jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(XML_STRING);
String json = jsonObj.toString(INDENTATION);
System.out.println(json);
```

gives "ItemName": 0

other than E, any character between numeric values is working fine.

Comment: Underscore-java library has a static method U.xmlToJson(xml).

Answer (score -1):

Hi ankur try with this npm: 'xml-js'.

```
const convert = require('xml-js');

convertXml2Json(xml) {
let xmlTemp = xml;
xmlTemp = xmlTemp.replace(/&/g, '&amp;');

let jsonResult = convert.xml2json(xmlTemp, { compact: true, spaces: 0 });
jsonResult = JSON.parse(jsonResult);

return jsonResult;
```

}

Comment: May I know the reason for above issue!

Comment: Excuse me, I think it could also be because of the leading zeros

Comment: And because of the version of your npm it may not be the right one, that's why I use the library that I showed you as an example.